# when i try to remove object from array list getting java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 3

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin

**Below is the log of the how my data is being stored:

2022-10-06 17:00:29.453 13090-13090/com.app E/check: [com.app.views.Module.DataClass.UserDataClass@7db605b, com.app.views.Module.DataClass.UserDataClass@a4e07fb]

When i try to remove the object from list (when it is already present in the array list)it gives index out of bound error.

```
 override fun onNewClick(
        name: String?,
        id: String?,
        phoneno: String?,
        image: String?,
        username: String?,
        position: Int
    ) {
    if (countChatList.contains(id)) {
                countChatList.remove(id)
                imageList.remove(image)
            if (userDataList.size > 1) {
                var bbbb = userDataList.get(position)
                userDataList.remove(bbbb)
            }
        
    } else {
        countChatList.add(id.toString())
        var bbbb = UserDataClass()
        bbbb.id = id
        bbbb.picture = image
        if (username!!.isEmpty()) {
            bbbb.username = phoneno
        } else if (phoneno!!.isEmpty()) {
            bbbb.username = username
        } else if (username.isNotEmpty() && phoneno.isNotEmpty()) {
            bbbb.username = username
        }
        bbbb.name = name
       
        userDataList.add(bbbb)
    }
}
```

**Adapter call**

```
itemView.setOnClickListener {
                o.isSelected = o.isSelected != true
                notifyItemChanged(position)
                itemListner.onNewAllChatsClick(
                    o.name,
                    o.Id,
                    o.phoneNo,
                    o.image,
                    o.username,
                    position
                )
            }
```

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong here.
And why i am getting list in [com.app.views.Module.DataClass.UserDataClass@7db605b, com.app.views.Module.DataClass.UserDataClass@a4e07fb] such manner.

**How to remove element in such way that i dont get index out of bound error?**

Comment: You simply must be calling this function with a `position` larger than the size of the `userDataList`

Comment: @Ivo

So what should i do here. after adding object in list when i print log i am getting userdataList.ToList in [com.app.views.Module.DataClass.UserDataClass@7db605b, com.app.views.Module.DataClass.UserDataClass@a4e07fb] in such format. i am not able to remove that object from list.

Comment: I  can't judge what `position` actually is from what you've shown. But it must be higher than the size od the userDataList. That print is just what a list of objects looks like. Nothing wrong there. `[com.app.views.Module.DataClass.UserDataClass@7db605b, com.app.views.Module.DataClass.UserDataClass@a4e07fb] ` just means a list with 2 objects of type `UserDataClass`.

Answer (score 0):

i have created another list stored that in that list as well and removed the data using the secondary list which is deleteDataList.

```
   if (userDataList.size > 0) {
        for (i in deleteDataList.indices){
            val UserDataClass = deleteDataList[i]
                        
            if (UserDataClass.id.equals(id)){
                  userDataList.remove(UserDataClass)
            }
   }
```

For the above solution i didnt even required the position.